# Swift remove a button BottomBorder

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit

So I have buttons that add a nice border when clicked, I cannot find a way to remove the borders, because I only want one border at a time. I have tried setting the width to 0 etc.

```
@IBAction func podsButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    podsButton.addBottomBorderWithColor(color: greenColor(), width: 3)
}

@IBAction func subscribedButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    subscribedButton.addBottomBorderWithColor(color: greenColor(), width: 3)
}

@IBAction func subscribersButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    subscribersButton.addBottomBorderWithColor(color: greenColor(), width: 3)
}
```

In each button I would like to remove the border from the others, per se.

Comment: The method addBottomBorderWithColor is NOT Apple API.  You should tell us which library defines it.. And it's recommended to check their docs how they remove it. and if they don't, check how they apply it, so you can remove it by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addBottomBorderWithColor` is, I'm guessing, a method you have added as an extension of `UIButton` in your project. Depending on how it adds the bottom border you'll have to do one of the following:

If you are adding the bottom border of the button as a subview, you'll need to create a method that does the following:

```
func removeBottomBorder() {
    bottomBorder.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

If, instead, you are adding the bottom border as a sublayer, you'll need to do this:

```
func removeBottomBorder() {
    bottomBorder.removeFromSuperlayer()
}
```

I recommend you create a custom button subclass that manages the bottom border, it will be more or less similar to this:

```
class BottomBorderButton: UIButton {
    var bottomBorder: UIView? // If you are using a CALayer, use that instead

    func addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: Int) {
        let bottomBorder = UIView() // If you are using a CALayer, use that instead
        // Use whatever you have already implementeds here
        // ...
        self.bottomBorder = bottomBorder
    }

    func removeBottomBorder() {
        self.bottomBorder?.removeFromSuperview()
        // If you use a CALayer, use the following instead
        // self.bottomBorder?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

On your project then use BottomBorderButton instead of UIButton where needed.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I had a class extension, but it wouldn't let me store properties. Your solution worked beautifully. Thank you.